How to remove connecting lines in the line plot for large dataset?
i have a large dataset of around 4000 line, and with python i want to plot all the lines in graph, but as showen in the figure below all the time shows those lines connecting the start and the end of each curve.
So, how can i remove the connecting line in the graph ?
(https://i.sstatic.net/6WWGhnBM.png)

sort your datapoints x-wise before plotting them

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
